# Decrypting a file from KMS using Python failed with error "400 Decryption failed: the ciphertext is invalid"

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I've encrypted a password string using the Python client library, write the contents to a file, uploaded it to GCS. Next when I download the file, read the contents and decrypt it using the same client library, it is giving me this error.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Decryption failed: the ciphertext is invalid.
```

I'm using this [code](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#decrypt) to encrypt and decrypt

Comment: It's difficult to say without a full code sample, but my guess is base64-encoding. When you encrypted it, you probably `| base64`. You need to `| base64 --decode` before trying to decrypt it. If you can share more code, I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to figure out without code. However, Below are the basic steps for using Google Cloud KMS service.

**Steps for encryption:**

1. Encode plaintext in base64.
2. Encrypt the data.
3. Encode binary ciphertext in base64.

**Steps for decryption:**

1. Decode base64 ciphertext.
2. Decrypt the data.
3. Decode base64 decrypted text to plaintext.

**Sample Python Code:**

```
from google.cloud import kms_v1
from google.cloud.kms_v1 import enums
import base64

def encrypt_symmetric(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, crypto_key_id, plaintext):
    # Creates an API client for the KMS API.
    client = kms_v1.KeyManagementServiceClient()
    # The resource name of the CryptoKey.
    name = client.crypto_key_path_path(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id,crypto_key_id)

    # Base64 Encoding of plaintext
    plaintext = base64.b64encode(plaintext)
    # Encrypt the data
    response = client.encrypt(name, plaintext)
    # Base64 Encoding of ciphertext
    ciphertext = base64.b64encode(response.ciphertext)
    return ciphertext

def decrypt_symmetric(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, crypto_key_id, ciphertext):
    # Creates an API client for the KMS API.
    client = kms_v1.KeyManagementServiceClient()
    # The resource name of the CryptoKey.
    name = client.crypto_key_path_path(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, crypto_key_id)

    # Decode Base64 ciphertext
    ciphertext = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
    # Decrypt the data
    response = client.decrypt(name, ciphertext)
    # Decode Base64 plaintext
    plaintext = base64.b64decode(response.plaintext)
    return plaintext


if __name__=='__main__':
    project_id = 'Your-project-id'
    location_id = 'your-location'
    key_ring_id = 'Key-ring-id'
    crypto_key_id = 'crypto-key-id'
    plaintext = 'Vikas Saini'
    ciphertext = encrypt_symmetric(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, crypto_key_id, plaintext)
    print ciphertext
    plaintext = decrypt_symmetric(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, crypto_key_id, ciphertext)
    print plaintext
```

Hope this helps.